# If the restriction of two continuous linear functions are equal, then are these two functions equal?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space and let $M$ be a linear subspace of $X$. Let $f,g\in X^*$ be such that $f|_M=g|_M$. Then can we get $f=g$?

Or do we need $M$ being dense to get $f=g$? If so, how to prove it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Of course this isn't true.  $f\mid_{\{0\}}=g\mid_{\{0\}}$ for all $f,g\in X^*$

Comment: @Aweygan Can we get $f=g$ if $M$ is dense? Thank you!

Comment: Let  $X$ be a Hilbert space, or any $l_p$ space with $1\leq p<\infty.$ . If  $\|f\|=\|f|_M\|=\|g|_M\| =\|g\|$ and if  $ f|_M=g|_M$  then $f=g$.  In other words, 
 the extension of  some member of $M^*$  to a member of $X^*,$  with the same norm, is unique.This does not hold for an infinite-dimensional   $ l_{\infty}.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first statement is not true, as we can take any $f\in X^*$ nonzero, let $g=\lambda f$ for some nonunit scalar $\lambda$, and let $M=\ker(f)$.

The second statement is true, and follows by continuity.  Suppose $M$ is dense, and $f=g$ on $M$.  Then $f-g=0$ on $M$, and by continuity $f-g=0$ on $X$.  To be more precise, fix $x\in X$ and $\varepsilon>0$.  Since $f-g$ is continuous, there is some $\delta>0$ such that $|(f-g)(x-y)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $\|x-y\|<\delta$.  Since $M$ is dense, there is some $y\in M$ with $\|x-y\|<\delta$, and thus $|(f-g)(x)|=|(f-g)(x-y)|<\varepsilon$.  Since $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary, $(f-g)(x)=0$, and since $x\in X$ was arbitrary, $f-g=0$.

Comment: As an alternate proof: $\Delta_{\mathbb{R}} = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x = y \}$ is closed since $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff; since $f$ and $g$ are continuous, $(f, g) : X \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is continuous; and $\{ x\in X \mid f(x) = g(x) \} = (f, g)^{-1}(\Delta_X)$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: This shows that $\{ x \mid f(x) = g(x) \}$ is closed, and contains $M$ which is dense, so it must be all of $X$.

Comment: @Aweygan Is this proof ok? Let $x\in X$. Then there exits a net $(x_n)$ in $M$ such that $x_n\rightarrow x$ since $M$ is dense. Since $f,g\in X^*$, $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x)$ and $g(x_n)\rightarrow g(x)$. Since $f|_M=g|_M$, $f(x_n)=g(x_n)\rightarrow g(x)$. By the uniqueness of the limit, $f(x)=g(x)$; that is, $f=g$.

Comment: @AnswerLee Yes, that proof works (and the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff is used in concluding the uniqueness of the limit).

Comment: @DanielSchepler Ahh yes, and that has the added benefit of proving for the more general case that $X$ is not formed but a TVS.

Comment: I think the added benefit is more for the case where the codomain is a general Hausdorff space - as opposed to the case where the codomain is a topological group and you can just use $f \cdot g^{-1}$ as a generalization of $f-g$.  (Though actually, a topological group is Hausdorff if and only if it's $T_1$ if and only if it's $T_0$...)

Answer (score 0):

Take $f,g\colon \Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$ where $f(x,y)=xy$ and $g(x,y)=0$. Then $f|_{\Bbb R\times\{0\}}=g|_{\Bbb R\times\{0\}}$ since both are identically $0$, but $f\neq g$ since $f(1,1)\neq g(1,1)$.

Comment: Can we get $f=g$ if $M$ is dense? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it follows from the definition of continuity.

Comment: I am sorry that I am new to analysis. Can you give a little prove? Thank you so much!

Comment: Your $f$ is not linear!

Comment: Sorry; missed that part. See @Aweygan

Answer (score 0):

Consider the normed space $(C[-1,1], \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ and two functionals $F,G \in C[-1,1]^*$ given by

$$F(f) = \int_{-1}^1 f(x)\,dx, \qquad \quad G(f) = 2\int_{0}^1 f(x)\,dx$$

for all $f \in C[-1,1]$.

Then $F \ne G$ but $F$ and $G$ coincide on the subspace of even continuous functions on $[-1,1]$.